# Need synchronous behavior in angular js 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Background: I have one Web API with GET method and returning the boolean value.
Once I receive this value then I need to perform some action.

Issue: My code is reaching to the condition where I am checking this boolean value before the API return the value. I am unable to wait until the API returns the value. In below code Javascript execution is reaching to "setTimeout" statement.

My R&D: I have applied this setTimeout to delay the execution but still the value is coming late from api and javascript is processing.

Code: using AngularJS 1.6 version 
I have tried both way using $http.get() and $http({//setting the confiuration here});

actual code:
1. code where I am calling the service

```
paymentFormRoleValidationBeforeSubmit: function (contractId, payFormId) {
        return $http({
            url: 'some api url',
            method: "GET",
            headers: serviceheader,
            config: serviceconfig
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, serviceheader) {
            return data.value;
        }).error(function (data, status, header, serviceheader) {
                console.log("** Fail -- before submitting role checked is failed.")
                return false;
        });
    }
```

2. javascript code where I am calling this one

   ```
   if (workflowStatus == "Start") {
           var returnHttp = $paymentFormsService.paymentFormRoleValidationBeforeSubmit(parseInt($rootScope.contractId), parseInt($rootScope.payFormId));
                       flagValue = returnHttp;
                   }
   ```
3. Inside this fire method I am checking whether flagValue is true or false and then executing some other task, but this value is coming undefine and the else part is executing

   setTimeout(fire(workflowStatus, flagValue), 5000);

   function fire(workflowStatus, flagValue){
    if (flagValue === true) {
        // if value is true then save in database.
    }
    else{
       // Here I am displaying an error popup on UI screen
    }
   }

But in my case I am getting error popup everytime, because the API has not yet return the value and flagValue is undefined. and this popup get dispalyed. After that in then API return the value it is working in async way.

Or is there any other way to do it please update me.. This is my production issue.

Comment: Sorry to sound polemic, but it's the other way round: You need **asynchronous** behavior and you'll have to restructure your application accordingly. Everything else will lead to a mess.

Comment: If you want to make a synchronous http request, you'll need to use a raw [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). I do recommend stronly against this. Running anything synchronous in javascript, makes the browser halt - so if your guest makes any action while the request is running, his browser will warn him and prompt him to stop the process. That's horrible UX wise.

Comment: Thanks guys, actually I have edited the code section again, there is one fire method which I am using where I am checking the "flagValue" variable's value.
If this value is true then no issue, if it is false there I am displaying some Error on UI screen in some popup. so in this case everytime when I am putting the correct value I am receiving the error popup because the API has not yet return the value and "flagValue" is undefiend and else condition is executed.

Comment: Also, using `success` and `error` callbacks has been deprecated in angular 1.6. Your code is not really returning a promise. Use `then` instead, as per the `$http`-documentation.

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen : If I use the promise  and use the then method it will be the again async way isn't it?

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen : can you please update the code with promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do your http request in your service and get your promise where you call the service. This way you can set your flag when your http call returns a promise.

service

```
paymentFormRoleValidationBeforeSubmit = function (contractId, payFormId) {
    var request = $http({
        url: 'some api url',
        method: "GET",
        headers: serviceheader,
        config: serviceconfig
    });
    return request;
}
```

code where you call the service

```
var promiseGet = $paymentFormsService.paymentFormRoleValidationBeforeSubmit(parseInt($rootScope.contractId), parseInt($rootScope.payFormId));;
promiseGet.then(function (returnHttp) {
    flagValue = returnHttp;
},
function (errorPl) {

});
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.